# Php resize image height, which gets loaded from a remote site

Tags: php, resize

Im loading some images from a remote site. The images are coming with little dupplicates under themself. So im trying to cut those little copys of the main image off.

See http://testing.zwiink.us/image/ for an example. Just leave the username in the form element as it is.

**Question:** Is there any way, to cut 200 pixels height of the image off? For example picture format:

**Old:**

Height:500px;
Width:500px;

**New:**

Height:300px;
Width:500px;

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022610/download-image-from-remote-source-and-resize-then-save

Answer (score 0):

use Imagick class! http://php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php
and it's static method "`Imagick::chopImage()`"
http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.chopimage.php